# が and passive verb referring to modified noun

Tags: grammar

落ち葉が敷き詰められた庭。

Why is the passive form used here?

Is it because it's reffering to 庭?

I thought with passive it should have been:

庭は落ち葉に敷き詰められた。

Can someone explain the rule here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get 落ち葉が敷き詰められた庭 by turning 庭に落ち葉が敷き詰められた。 into a relative clause.

---

Here are the non-relative active voice sentences:

> 落ち葉**を**庭**に**敷き詰めた。/
>   庭**を**落ち葉**で**敷き詰めた。

Their passive voice equivalents would be:

> 落ち葉**が**庭に敷き詰められた。/
>   庭**が**落ち葉で敷き詰められた。

Turning them into relative clauses, you'll get:

> 「（庭に敷き詰められた）落ち葉」「（落ち葉が敷き詰められた）庭」/
>   「（落ち葉で敷き詰められた）庭」

Comment: Isn't 敷き詰める=to cover a surface?

落ち葉を庭に敷き詰めた。/
庭を落ち葉で敷き詰めた。

Why are you using 落ち葉を in the first active sentence?
I would think that 落ち葉 is doing the action of covering 庭.
I would say 落ち葉が庭を敷き詰めた。

I do not understand why am i wrong.

Isn't the direct object 庭 and the subject 落ち葉?

Comment: [敷き詰める](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%95%B7%E3%81%8D%E8%A9%B0%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) means 「すき間のないように**敷く** 」 (not 覆う), which is like "(for someone) to fully cover (something with something)", the subject of which should be people, as in 「(人が)[物]を[場所]に敷き詰める」