# relative clause with Causative-Passive Verb

Tags: particles, syntax, passive-voice, relative-clauses, causation

In this grammatical construction:

> X (doer)-は/が + Y (place)-で\に + Z (causer)-に + W (direct object)-を + Causative-Passive Verb (transitive verb)

What particles are used if the following relative clause is formed (hypothetically)?

> Causer-( ) + Direct Object-( ) + Doer-( ) + Causative-Passive Verb + Place

I think that the most normal and understandable construction would be a causative-passive verb modifying the doer, but given this answer [passive verb modifying a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29035/%E3%81%8C-and-passive-verb-referring-to-modified-noun)... I wonder the arrangement of the sentence with this verb conjugation.

Comment: By definition nothing is changed if you make the original subject into the clause topic?

Comment: @Derpius I don't think I understand your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> X (doer)-は/が + Y (place)-で\に + Z (causer)-に + W (direct object)-を + Causative-Passive Verb (transitive verb)

I am not 100% sure but if you mean something like:

> - 山田さん**は**その教室**で**佐藤先生**に**宿題**を**させられた。
>     (Yamada-san was made to do her homework by Sato-sensei in that classroom.)
> - 太郎君**は**カラオケボックス**で**次郎君**に**演歌**を**歌わされた。
>     (Taro-kun was made to sing Enka by Jiro-kun at a karaoke bar.)
> - 僕**は**その店**で**彼女**に**バッグ**を**買わされた。
>     (I was made to buy a bag by/for her/my gf at that store.)

Then you can turn them into a relative clause this way:

> Causer-( ) + Direct Object-( ) + Doer-( ) + Causative-Passive Verb + Place

(Normal word order would be "Doerが + Causerに + Objectを + Causative-passive verb + Place")

-->

> - 山田さん**が**佐藤先生**に**宿題**を**させられた教室
>     (a classroom where Yamada-san was made to do her homework by Sato-sensei)
> - 太郎君**が**次郎君**に**演歌**を**歌わされたカラオケボックス
>     (a karaoke bar where Taro-kun was made to sing Enka by Jiro-kun)
> - 僕**が**彼女**に**バッグ**を**買わされた店
>     (a store where I was made to buy a bag by/for her/my gf)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, if you provide an example in English I could translate it.

Generally there are two main constructions, passive and non-passive. Normal is 田中さんは石を落とした (Tanaka dropped a rock), passive is 田中さんに石が落とされた。(the rock was dropped by Tanaka) This should not be confused with transitive or intransitive verbs, which basically just say if "someone caused the action" or "the action happened". (e.g. 落とす I drop a rock, 落ちる a rock falls)

> 犯人にお金が盗まれたところ
>   by the thief, the money that was stolen, the place where
>
> the place where the money was stolen by the thief.

> 犯人がお金を盗んだところ
>   the money, that the thief stole, the place where
>
> the place where the thief stole the money.